# Sysinternals Process Explorer: don't close when pressing the escape key

Tags: process-explorer, sysinternals

I often accidentally close Process Explorer when I only want to close one of its dialogs, because I press the ESC key once too often. Quite annoying.

**Is there any way to configure Process Explorer to not close when the ESC key is pressed?**